# Meaning of UTS in UTS_RELEASE

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

`UTS_RELEASE` defines the kernel version in Linux. It's defined in `generated/utsrelease.h`, which is created by [the main Makefile](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git;a=blob;f=Makefile;h=540f7b240c77d7332f7c51746de660a709e6c431;hb=29594404d7fe73cd80eaa4ee8c43dcc53970c60e) like so:

```
# KERNELRELEASE can change from a few different places, meaning version.h
# needs to be updated, so this check is forced on all builds

uts_len := 64
define filechk_utsrelease.h
        if [ `echo -n "$(KERNELRELEASE)" | wc -c ` -gt $(uts_len) ]; then \
          echo '"$(KERNELRELEASE)" exceeds $(uts_len) characters' >&2;    \
          exit 1;                                                         \
        fi;                                                               \
        (echo \#define UTS_RELEASE \"$(KERNELRELEASE)\";)
endef
```

I was wondering what UTS stands for, here?

Comment: Added http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~mwalfish/cs395t//ref/ritchie74.pdf

Comment: What's so important about this that it has a bounty? It's not even a real programming question. And what's wrong with nullix's answer?

Comment: @Barmar My respect, I can do with it what I want :) Without joking, I'm just too curious what means this abbreviation. Understanding things helps to remember them too.

Comment: In Android, it goes here: Settings > About Phone > Kernel Version

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I will do a bet : it comes from unix history age.
Unix Time Sharing 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-sharing

( with another link to give more weight to my guess : http://www.linuxmisc.com/9-unix-programmer/515225795f89ebf5.htm )

Additionally if you search for UTS on Wikipedia you'll find this as evidence too:

**UTS is a three-letter abbreviation which may describe:**

- Time-sharing, known as Unix Time-sharing System (UTS) when abbreviated in the source code of many Unix-like operating systems

Answer (score 3):

Maybe https://lwn.net/Articles/531114/ and https://lwn.net/Articles/179345/ are the right(tm) answer :-)

Comment: From the 1st link "The name of that structure in turn derives from "UNIX Time-sharing System", so the accepted answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

For example, if `KERNELRELEASE` value is:

```
3.18.31-g18e453b
```

Also in the file

```
*utsrelease.h
```

Will be:

```
#define UTS_RELEASE "3.18.31-g18e453b"
```

In Android, it goes here:

```
Settings > About Phone > Kernel Version
```